# Truncating a table with a foreign key constraint - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-key, truncate

I have two tables in a SQL Server Database, `StudentAttendance` and `Attendance` with the following structure:

**Attendance**

- AttendanceID
- TimeTableID
- AttendanceDate
- UserName

**StudentAttendance**

- StudentAttendanceID
- AttendanceID
- StudentID
- IsPresent

I run the following query and it works:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE StudentAttendance
```

But the following query gives me an error:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Attendance
```

> Msg 4712, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Cannot truncate table 'Attendance'
>   because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Why do I get the above error even though the `Attendance` table is empty?

Comment: Doesn’t matter if the table is empty. You need to either drop and re-create the foreign key constraint or just perform a delete instead of a truncate. How often are you really just emptying both tables?

Comment: @AaronBertrand rarely, I don't want this operation to be logged in transaction log that's why I wanted to use truncate instead of delete operation.

Comment: Then drop the constraint(s), truncate, and re-create the constraints.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [TRUNCATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is fairly clear on this topic.

Referencing the **Restrictions**:

> You cannot use TRUNCATE TABLE on tables that:
>
> Are referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (You can truncate a table
>   that has a foreign key that references itself.)

---

Regarding your comment

> *I don't want this operation to be logged in transaction log that's why*
>   *I wanted to use truncate instead of delete operation.*

The `TRUNCATE TABLE` command is fully logged, just not at the row level.  Within a transaction, it can be rolled back.

Referencing the **REMARKS** section of the documentation.

> Less transaction log space is used.
>
> The DELETE statement removes rows one at a time and records an entry
>   in the transaction log for each deleted row. TRUNCATE TABLE removes
>   the data by deallocating the data pages used to store the table data
>   and records only the page deallocations in the transaction log.